# Cubic Polynomial With an Extra Variable

Tags: polynomials

I was trying so desperately to find the value of $c$. Let

$$P(x) = 2x^3+2x^2-2cx+4$$

$x+2$ is the factor of $P(x)$. So I started factoring it, going $x+2(2x^2-2x...$ and then got stuck at factoring $2cx$. It just seems impossible, because 4 does not have $c$ with it.

What I need here is the process with which to solve this problem, not an answer. My explanation book just tells me to graph it, saying it's the fastest way. But I don't want to.

Comment: Hint: Suppose that the polynomial $P(x)$ has factor $x+2$. Then $P(x)=(x+2)Q(x)$ for some polynomial $Q(x)$, and therefore $P(-2)=0$.

Comment: Is it $2^x$ or $x^2$?

Comment: I flagged the answer for removal and so will respond on donotcopy's behalf.  It's $2x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing $P(x)$ by $x+2$ you have the residu equal to zero which give you $c=1$ and you get finally $$P(x)=2(x+2)(x^2-x+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x+2$ is a factor of $P(x)$, then we know that $$P(x) = (x+2)Q(x)$$ for some polynomial $Q(x)$.  It follows that $x = -2$ is a root of $P(x)$, since $$P(-2) = (-2 + 2)Q(-2) = 0.$$  Consequently, $$0 = 2(-2)^3 + 2(-2)^2 -2c (-2) + 4,$$ from which the value of $c$ is trivially deduced.